# Boolean value tricks if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a custom header value and the values I receive are correct. The expected values are: **true, false, undefined**.
However, the response based on such value: **false** is not correct.

**Snippet**

```
let isMobileDevice = req.headers["is-mobile-device"];
console.log(isMobileDevice);

if(isMobileDevice) {
    console.log("Mobile client");
    return res.sendStatus(200);
}
else {
    console.log("Web Client");
    return res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

**Output**

```
[0] undefined
[0] Web Client
[0] POST /api/v1/authorization 200 92.690 ms - 2
[0] false
[0] Mobile client
[0] POST /api/v1/authorization 200 76.601 ms - 2
[0] true
[0] Mobile client
[0] POST /api/v1/authorization 200 74.978 ms - 2
```

I might be doing something wrong but I really can't find where.

Comment: Are you sure it's `false` instead of `'false'`?

Comment: Could you also log `typeof isMobileDevice` like `console.log(isMobileDevice, typeof isMobileDevice);`

Comment: @LW001 you were right. Its a string and not a boolean. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values you get in `isMobileDevice` are not booleans (`true`, `false`) but strings (`'true'`, `'false'`).
When evaluated in boolean context, both are equivalent to `true` (boolean).

You should compare `isMobileDevice` against a string:

```
if (isMobileDevice === 'true') {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

When used in boolean context (i.e. as conditions) `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN` are considered `false`, all the other values are considered `true`.
Read more about the *truthy* value in JavaScript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 2):

Check for the values to be strings as well, not just boolean, since `false` is not the same as `'false'`. Same with `true` and `'true'`.

```
    let isMobileDevice = req.headers["is-mobile-device"];
    console.log(isMobileDevice);

    if(isMobileDevice==true || isMobileDevice=='true') {
        console.log("Mobile client");
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Web Client");
        return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
```

Comment: buddy it's preferable to use `===` instead of `==` in javascript. Well your concept is right though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know javascript but...

Most likely it's because isMobileDevice is a string type and will always evaluate to true as long as it isn't ""

Try if(isMobileDevice == "true")

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the `if condition` as below

```
if (Boolean(isMobileDevice)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```